# How to lock or fix scrolling when last image or div is reaches specified point from top of browser?

Tags: css, html, scroll, position, height

Hi I'm pretty new to html and CSS and have come across a problem that I can't seem to find a solution to anywhere. I've asked web design friends who are also puzzled, I'm hoping someone out there can assist.

This link takes you to the project page I'm working on: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25715164/project01.html

I've run into a massive problem with how to limit scrolling until the last div on a page aligns with just under the title. Currently when viewed through a browser window that fills the edges of the screen it works okay with the second image aligning just below the title line. However when you start scaling the browser window the divs dont line up properly and either leave a weird big gap between title and image or the image is too far beyond the top of the screen. if you follow the links you'll hopefully see what i mean?

I've tried playing with margins, padding, div height, and was considering if the last image were a footer instead but I haven't managed to crack it!

I thought this might be simple in that the page should contain a fixed div title at the top and then content that would scroll by until the top of the final image is about 30px from the top of the browser window at which point scrolling would be disabled - I'm completely stumped and any help you can give would be much appreciated. The html and external CSS is copied below. [i started this site using dreamweaver cs6's new liquid layout but the scaling was a little glitchy and after a lot of research advice generally pointed towards a fixed pxel relatively positioned container div, centered on page with absolute positioned divs inside]

Thanks in advance.

```
/* html */


<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the     file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr     (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your     modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="gridContainer clearfix">

<div id="fixedtop1">
    <div id="center250a">
            <div id="SiteHeadingPortfolio_test">PORTFOLIO</div> 
      <div id="SiteHeaderPSIdesign_test"> &nbsp;: PRODUCT / SERVICE / INTERACTION DESIGN</div>
      <div id="HorizontalRule_test"><hr></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="project01_wrap"><img src="images/test.png"></div>
<div class="project02_wrap"><img src="images/test.png"></div>






</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>
</html>


/* CSS CODE */


@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("webfonts/Ben_Sans_Bold/stylesheet.css");
@import url("webfonts/Ben_Sans_Regular/stylesheet.css");
@import url("webfonts/Ben_Sans_Light/stylesheet.css");
@import url("webfonts/Ben_Sans_RegularItalic/stylesheet.css");

img, object, embed, video {
max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
width:100%;
}

/*
Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
----------------------------------
dw-num-cols-mobile:     4;
dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
dw-num-cols-desktop:    10;
dw-gutter-percentage:   20;

Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
width: 370px;
padding-left: 0%;
padding-right: 0%;
margin: auto;
}



/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
.gridContainer {
width: 1000px;
max-width: 1000px;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
padding-top: 10px;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
#SiteHeadingPortfolio {
width: 78px;
display: block;
font-family: "Ben Sans Bold";
font-size: 11.5px;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
position: absolute;
}
body {
text-align: center;
}

.SiteHeaderPSIdesign {
margin-top: 2px;
font-family: "Ben Sans Regular";
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
position: absolute;
width: 350px;
left: 38px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
top: 9px;
}

.HorizontalRule {
left: 10px;
top: 22px;
height: 0px;
width: 980px;
position: absolute;
font-family: "Ben Sans Regular";
font-size: 5px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.button_01 {
position: absolute;
height: 185px;
width: 173px;
left: 15px;
top: 38px;
}
.button_image {
position: absolute;
height: 131px;
width: 173px;
}
.button_Title {
position: absolute;
width: 173px;
top: 135px;
font-family: "Ben Sans Regular";
font-size: 11px;
text-align: left;
}
.button_Text {
position: absolute;
width: 160px;
top: 149px;
font-family: "Ben Sans Regular";
font-size: 9px;
left: 15px;
text-align: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #333;
line-height: 14px;
word-spacing: 1.5pt;
}



/* Project Page begins here - TESTING -. */

.project01_wrap {
width: 980px;
height: 670px;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 38px;
}

.project02_wrap {
width: 980px;
height: 764px;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 800px;
}

#fixedtop1 { position: fixed; top: 10px; left: 0; right: 0; border: none; z-index: 50;     background-color: #FFFFFF; }
#center250a {
width: 980px;
margin: auto;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#SiteHeadingPortfolio_test {
width: 78px;
display: block;
font-family: "Ben Sans Bold";
font-size: 11.5px;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
position: absolute;
}

#SiteHeaderPSIdesign_test {
margin-left: 28px;
margin-top: 1.5px;
font-family: "Ben Sans Regular";
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
position: absolute;
width: 350px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#HorizontalRule_test {
margin-left: 0px;
top: 12px;
height: 0px;
width: 980px;
position: absolute;
font-family: "Ben Sans Regular";
font-size: 5px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting into very tricky territory when you are trying to rely on the size of a client's viewport.

If you're really set on doing that there's two ways you can attempt it. First by using JS/jQuery to detect the viewport size and dynamically alter your page to get the desired effect, or by using CSS media queries to do the same thing.

Realistically though using either of those techniques would take a lot of effort for very little reward. Why not simply make your fixed position header have a white background so that it looks OK whatever is behind it?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I totally get what your saying, i plan on making the header have a white background but the problem is not being able to see the images go past it. I'm trying to ensure the last image of all the content cannot scroll beyond the title;- so when you reach the bottom of the page, it is aligned perfectly within the viewing area. Does this make sense?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but there are so many variables at play. What if the client's viewport is smaller than the image? It gets very tricky.

Comment: Okay I get what your saying about browser height and sorry to draw this out more. But what about wikipedia: and how if the user clicks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div

on wikipedia if you click one of the Contents chapters, it takes you straight to a heading. this is more complicated than what i require. i get that what i would do is perhaps over the top but I'm keen to understand why? as i said above, i'm still finding my feet in this.

Comment: Maximize your viewport, then click on "External links" in that Wikipedia article. Notice that the "External links" header is not at the top, unlike clicking on the other links. The distance between the "External links" header and the top of the page is dependant on the size of the client's viewport. You seem to be wanting to control that distance between the top of the page and the final image. The "External links" is running into the same issue that you would have with your final image.

Comment: Okay cool I know what you mean. A friend sent me this: http://jsfiddle.net/e4VzT/

which I am wanting to attempt to tweak to fit what I'm doing as a test to see how it works. Can't seem to stop it scrolling on for ages after it hits the div though. Any ideas?